# Which Type of FeedItem Records can I import?

Tags: chatter, migration, feeditem

I am facing a SF to SF migration and despite all efforts to avoid it, chatter posts have to be migrated as well. I wanted to know which types of chatter posts I am actually able to create via the API since I know there are restrictions (e.g. tracked field changes).

So far I have found [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) which states:

> Type : The type of FeedItem. Except for ContentPost, LinkPost, and TextPost, don’t create FeedItem types directly from the API.

Does anyone know if there is another way to import other types of chatter posts (FeedItem)? Also if you have any pointers as to hidden complexities, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: if worst comes to worst, you can create a custom object `Feeditem__c` with an external Id to the parent object and then a custom VF or Lightning component to show the legacy feed items. We did something like this when migrating field audit trail history. Doable, no pleasant though